# AjaxControlToolkit ModalPopup in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a `DashBoard` view.
On clicking on `Assign` button a ModalPopup Opens like : [image: PopUpView]

Code for opening PopUp

```
$create(AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupBehavior, 
    { 
        "BackgroundCssClass": "modalBackground", 
        "DropShadow": false, 
        "OkControlID": 
        "OkButton", 
        "OnOkScript": "onOk()", 
        "PopupControlID": "div_to_popup", 
        "id": "PopUpBox" 
    }, null, null, $get("day"+a));

function onOk(){
  // what to write here to save data on server
}
```

Comment: Did you want to ask something?

Comment: I want to ask what should I write in `function okOk()`.
I want to send all data in the popup back to server to save in database. How can I do that.

Comment: @Darin Can you advise me something on this. I am stuck on this problem for a whole day or may be an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

`$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "/Home/SaveEntry",
data: { "savedata": data },
success: successFunction,
error: errorFunction
});`

`

```
function successFunction() { 
    alert('Inserted in Table successfully');
}
```

```
function errorFunction(){
    alert('Some error occurred');
}
```

`
My Controller

`public void SaveEntry(string savedata)
        {
string[] temp = result.Split('|');
GS_ALLOCATION shift = new GS_ALLOCATION();
shift.EMP_CODE = decimal.Parse(temp[0]);
shift.ALLOC_DATE = DateTime.Parse(temp[2]);
shift.TEAM_CODE = temp[3];
shift.WWL_WEEK = temp[4];
shiftRepo.AddShift(shift);
}`

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do this with a [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) [plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/bpopup) of your choice.

I would advise against using the Ajax Control Toolkit with ASP.NET MVC at all, since it is both old and kind of hacky to begin with, and (more importantly) heavily targeted against WebForms development.

Comment: I don't have problem using Modal Popup. I am confused rather lost that how will I send the data from popup (ajaxify if possible); to save it on clicking `Ok` button.

Comment: @Vabs: What I mean to say is that the AjaxControlToolkit was built for use with ASP.NET WebForms and may depend on viewstate which doesn't exist in the MVC Framework. I would suggest that you construct a simple `<form>` which you show as a modal popup (see the plugin I linked to), and which simply submits on OK.